# Angular toggle directive from parent controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

How i can show/hide directive when some elements in parent controller has event?

```js
app.directive('rest', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: false,
    replace: true,

    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
   
    },   
    templateUrl: '<div ng-show="showDirective"></div>',
  }
});
```

```html
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  
  <rest></rest>
  
<div ng-click="showDirective = false"><div>   <!-- hide directive -->
<div ng-click="showDirective = true"><div> <!-- show directive -->
</div>
```

Comment: I am not seeing anything wrong with the code. Give me a plnkr to play with please. Make sure the value is changing on the parent controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, your mistake was "templateUrl" instead of "template". When you provide html inline, user "template", when you provide html in a separate html file, use "templateUrl" and provide a url to the template html:

http://plnkr.co/edit/xzqOvcjKYfWxazWfHWyS?p=preview

```
  .directive('rest', function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: false,
      replace: true,


  link: function(scope, elem, attr) {

  },   
  template: '<div ng-if = "showDirective" >Test</div>',
}
```